# Using Counts in python to subtract list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter, subtraction

I've worked out how to use "counter" to add lists of dictionarys with the code below

```
from collections import Counter
a = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 1},
     {'num': 'star2', 'count': 3}]
b = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 7},
      {'num': 'star2', 'count': 2},
      {'num': 'star3', 'count': 1}]
joint = sum((Counter({elem['num']: elem['count']}) for elem in a + b), Counter())
[{'num': num, 'count': counts} for num, counts in joint .items()]
```

However, when I try to subtract I get an error. For example:

```
from collections import Counter
a = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 1},
     {'num': 'star2', 'count': 3}]
b = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 7},
      {'num': 'star2', 'count': 2},
      {'num': 'star3', 'count': 1}]
joint = sum((Counter({elem['num']: elem['count']}) for elem in a - b), Counter())
[{'num': num, 'count': counts} for num, counts in joint .items()]
```

Is anyone aware of a work around to this? Or how I could approach this issue?

I've tried using the subtract function in counter but it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to achieve here? Subtract the elements in `b` from the elements in `a`? Please specify the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Counter accept negative counts, but if you don't mind about not having negative counts, this will work (just doing the two Counters separately):

```
from collections import Counter
a = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 1},
     {'num': 'star2', 'count': 3}]
b = [{'num': 'star1', 'count': 7},
      {'num': 'star2', 'count': 2},
      {'num': 'star3', 'count': 1}]
joint = sum((Counter({elem['num']: elem['count']}) for elem in a), Counter())
joint -= sum((Counter({elem['num']: elem['count']}) for elem in b), Counter())
[{'num': num, 'count': counts} for num, counts in joint .items()]
```

It outputs:

```
[{'num': 'star2', 'count': 1}]
```

The other values (star1 and star3) would both be less than 0 because they come to 1-7=-6 and 0-1=-1 respectively

Alternatively you can just not use counters and do it like this (this supports negative numbers and whatever operation you want):

```
a_info = {d['num']:d['count'] for d in a}
b_info = {d['num']:d['count'] for d in b}
[{'num':item, 'count': a_info.get(item, 0)-b_info.get(item, 0)} for item in set(a_info)|set(b_info)]
```